# Set value in a column in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have created a custom list with columns.

```
1. Location 
2. Location_MMYY(Not visible on form)
```

In New Item form of this list, on click of save button I want to set below value field 2.

```
Value from field 1 + "_" + Current Month(MM) + Current Year(YY)
```

I have been told that custom coding is not allowed.
Please help me with this, will really appreciate.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Location_MMYY should be a Calculated Field. In Formula of the field give something like this:

```
=Location&"_"&MONTH(Edited)&DAY(Edited)
```

This will put together value and month and day of last edit in this field.